# How can i come to know total number of downloads of an Appstore Application.?

Tags: ipad, ios4, app-store

How can i come to know total number of downloads of an Appstore Application.?
I have my itunes login. But can not find the option.

Comment: Are you using the iTunes Connect site? Do you have the proper access privileges?

Comment: Yes i have privelleges.But i do not know how to check.

Comment: You should be able to just login to iTunes Connect and then see the option for "Sales and Trends" - it should all be there. What do you currently see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not able to see a complete total from iTunes connect. It will only allow you to browse by day or week.

I'm using the iTunes Connect Mobile iPhone app to check stats longer back .. unfortunately only 26 weeks.